# How to map an Oracle View in Entity Framework

Tags: oracle11g, entity-framework-5, sql-view

Knowing that Entity Framework requires any table or view to have Primary Key, how can we map an Oracle View in Entity Framework?

In SQL Server with can force a column being recognized by Entity Framework as a "primary key" by adding `ISNULL`. Trying to do the same in Oracle using `NVL` doesn't work, EF complains that it couldn't recognizes any column as a "primary key".

So, how can we map an Oracle View in Entity Framework?

Comment: You could try simulating another primary key using `ROW_NUMBER` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: Thanks @JustinBicknell, but Visual Studio 2012's EmdGen tool will not recognize the row id. I think I cannot do that, because I can't alter the view.